# Modifying java array within a JSP input form

Tags: java, arrays, jsp

I am trying to modify a java array within an `<input>` tag in JSP

```
String[] userProperties = {"one", "two", "three"};
String[] propValues = new String[userProperties.length];
.
.
.

<% for(int i = 0; i < userProperties.length; i++) { %>
    <tr>        
        <td>
            <input type="text" size="30" maxlength="150" name="<%=propValues[i]%>" value="somevalue">
        </td>
    </tr>
<% } %>
.
.
.
```

I would like for there to be 3 input forms in this example, and for each form, the value entered by the user would be bound to the appropriate position in the `propValues` array once the submit button is clicked. I am modifying this based on older code that had `name` set to a local Java variable, and it was successful in being able to modify that variable. Is this not possible with arrays in JSP? I am aware that JSTL has a `<c:forEach>` tag that makes this simpler, but since I am working with a single file in a fairly aged codebase I want to keep the libraries it has access to consistent. Is this possible using `<%>` Java code blocks?

Answer (score 0):

```
//length will 3 but initialize with default value null.
 String[] propValues = new String[userProperties.length];
```

what you are trying to do is you are initializing variable `userProperties` and try to access array Variable `propValues` which actually contains `null`.

```
name="<%=propValues[i]%>" // set your name as a null.
```

So, all your three `input` have same name as a `null`. better to try this code

```
<input type="text" size="30" maxlength="150" name="<%=userProperties[i]%>" value="somevalue">
```

instead of

```
 <input type="text" size="30" maxlength="150" name="<%=propValues[i]%>" value="somevalue">
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I may be fundamentally misunderstanding how JSP works, then. I am trying to assign a value to `userProp[i]` through the input form, so if I made the change you suggested, would it then modify the elements of array `userProperties`? If so, do you suggest I initialize `userProp` as an array of 3 blank strings instead?